# SQL Command Add Database Diagramming

Tags: t-sql, ssms, database-diagramming

Is there a tsql command on sqlserver 2008 which can be run in order to enable Database Diagramming instead of this dialog appearing:

This database does not have one or more of the support objects required to use database diagramming.  Do you wish to create them?

Answer (score 4):

The script is a little too long to add here, but here's what you can do.
1) Create a new database.
2) Start sql server profiler
3) Click the "Database Diagrams" folder in management studio.
4) Clear the profiler.
5) Confirm the message box with a prompt to enable diagramming.
6) Profiler now contains the script that enabled diagramming.
7) Select the script in profiler and copy the output from the bottom pane.

Kim

Answer (score 1):

This is the code required to create the objects to enable database diagramming.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID(N''dbo.sysdiagrams'') IS NOT NULL
            return 0;

        CREATE TABLE dbo.sysdiagrams
        (
            name sysname NOT NULL,
            principal_id int NOT NULL,  -- we may change it to varbinary(85)
            diagram_id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
            version int,

            definition varbinary(max)
            CONSTRAINT UK_principal_name UNIQUE
            (
                principal_id,
                name
            )
        );


        /* Add this if we need to have some form of extended properties for diagrams */
        /*
        IF OBJECT_ID(N''dbo.sysdiagram_properties'') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE dbo.sysdiagram_properties
            (
                diagram_id int,
                name sysname,
                value varbinary(max) NOT NULL
            )
        END
        */

        IF OBJECT_ID(N''dbo.dtproperties'') IS NOT NULL
        begin
            insert into dbo.sysdiagrams
            (
                [name],
                [principal_id],
                [version],
                [definition]
            )
            select   
                convert(sysname, dgnm.[uvalue]),
                DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(N''dbo''),            -- will change to the sid of sa
                0,                          -- zero for old format, dgdef.[version],
                dgdef.[lvalue]
            from dbo.[dtproperties] dgnm
                inner join dbo.[dtproperties] dggd on dggd.[property] = ''DtgSchemaGUID'' and dggd.[objectid] = dgnm.[objectid] 
                inner join dbo.[dtproperties] dgdef on dgdef.[property] = ''DtgSchemaDATA'' and dgdef.[objectid] = dgnm.[objectid]

            where dgnm.[property] = ''DtgSchemaNAME'' and dggd.[uvalue] like N''_EA3E6268-D998-11CE-9454-00AA00A3F36E_'' 
            return 2;
        end
        return 1;
    END
    '


END

-- This sproc could be executed by any other users than dbo
IF IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
    EXEC dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_helpdiagrams') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_helpdiagrams
    (
        @diagramname sysname = NULL,
        @owner_id int = NULL
    )
    WITH EXECUTE AS N''dbo''
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @user sysname
        DECLARE @dboLogin bit
        EXECUTE AS CALLER;
            SET @user = USER_NAME();
            SET @dboLogin = CONVERT(bit,IS_MEMBER(''db_owner''));
        REVERT;
        SELECT
            [Database] = DB_NAME(),
            [Name] = name,
            [ID] = diagram_id,
            [Owner] = USER_NAME(principal_id),
            [OwnerID] = principal_id
        FROM
            sysdiagrams
        WHERE
            (@dboLogin = 1 OR USER_NAME(principal_id) = @user) AND
            (@diagramname IS NULL OR name = @diagramname) AND
            (@owner_id IS NULL OR principal_id = @owner_id)
        ORDER BY
            4, 5, 1
    END
    '


    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_helpdiagrams TO public
    DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_helpdiagrams TO guest
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition
    (
        @diagramname    sysname,
        @owner_id   int = null      
    )
    WITH EXECUTE AS N''dbo''
    AS
    BEGIN
        set nocount on

        declare @theId      int
        declare @IsDbo      int
        declare @DiagId     int
        declare @UIDFound   int

        if(@diagramname is null)
        begin
            RAISERROR (N''E_INVALIDARG'', 16, 1);
            return -1
        end

        execute as caller;
        select @theId = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID();
        select @IsDbo = IS_MEMBER(N''db_owner'');
        if(@owner_id is null)
            select @owner_id = @theId;
        revert; 

        select @DiagId = diagram_id, @UIDFound = principal_id from dbo.sysdiagrams where principal_id = @owner_id and name = @diagramname;
        if(@DiagId IS NULL or (@IsDbo = 0 and @UIDFound <> @theId ))
        begin
            RAISERROR (''Diagram does not exist or you do not have permission.'', 16, 1);
            return -3
        end

        select version, definition FROM dbo.sysdiagrams where diagram_id = @DiagId ; 
        return 0
    END
    '


    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition TO public
    DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition TO guest
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_creatediagram') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_creatediagram
    (
        @diagramname    sysname,
        @owner_id       int = null,     
        @version        int,
        @definition     varbinary(max)
    )
    WITH EXECUTE AS ''dbo''
    AS
    BEGIN
        set nocount on

        declare @theId int
        declare @retval int
        declare @IsDbo  int
        declare @userName sysname
        if(@version is null or @diagramname is null)
        begin
            RAISERROR (N''E_INVALIDARG'', 16, 1);
            return -1
        end

        execute as caller;
        select @theId = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(); 
        select @IsDbo = IS_MEMBER(N''db_owner'');
        revert; 

        if @owner_id is null
        begin
            select @owner_id = @theId;
        end
        else
        begin
            if @theId <> @owner_id
            begin
                if @IsDbo = 0
                begin
                    RAISERROR (N''E_INVALIDARG'', 16, 1);
                    return -1
                end
                select @theId = @owner_id
            end
        end
        -- next 2 line only for test, will be removed after define name unique
        if EXISTS(select diagram_id from dbo.sysdiagrams where principal_id = @theId and name = @diagramname)
        begin
            RAISERROR (''The name is already used.'', 16, 1);
            return -2
        end

        insert into dbo.sysdiagrams(name, principal_id , version, definition)
                VALUES(@diagramname, @theId, @version, @definition) ;

        select @retval = @@IDENTITY 
        return @retval
    END
    '


    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_creatediagram TO public
    DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_creatediagram TO guest
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_renamediagram') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_renamediagram
    (
        @diagramname        sysname,
        @owner_id       int = null,
        @new_diagramname    sysname

    )
    WITH EXECUTE AS ''dbo''
    AS
    BEGIN
        set nocount on
        declare @theId          int
        declare @IsDbo          int

        declare @UIDFound       int
        declare @DiagId         int
        declare @DiagIdTarg     int
        declare @u_name         sysname
        if((@diagramname is null) or (@new_diagramname is null))
        begin
            RAISERROR (''Invalid value'', 16, 1);
            return -1
        end

        EXECUTE AS CALLER;
        select @theId = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID();
        select @IsDbo = IS_MEMBER(N''db_owner''); 
        if(@owner_id is null)
            select @owner_id = @theId;
        REVERT;

        select @u_name = USER_NAME(@owner_id)

        select @DiagId = diagram_id, @UIDFound = principal_id from dbo.sysdiagrams where principal_id = @owner_id and name = @diagramname 
        if(@DiagId IS NULL or (@IsDbo = 0 and @UIDFound <> @theId))
        begin
            RAISERROR (''Diagram does not exist or you do not have permission.'', 16, 1)
            return -3
        end

        -- if((@u_name is not null) and (@new_diagramname = @diagramname))  -- nothing will change
        --  return 0;

        if(@u_name is null)
            select @DiagIdTarg = diagram_id from dbo.sysdiagrams where principal_id = @theId and name = @new_diagramname
        else
            select @DiagIdTarg = diagram_id from dbo.sysdiagrams where principal_id = @owner_id and name = @new_diagramname

        if((@DiagIdTarg is not null) and  @DiagId <> @DiagIdTarg)
        begin
            RAISERROR (''The name is already used.'', 16, 1);
            return -2
        end     

        if(@u_name is null)
            update dbo.sysdiagrams set [name] = @new_diagramname, principal_id = @theId where diagram_id = @DiagId
        else
            update dbo.sysdiagrams set [name] = @new_diagramname where diagram_id = @DiagId
        return 0
    END
    '


    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_renamediagram TO public
    DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_renamediagram TO guest
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_alterdiagram') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_alterdiagram
    (
        @diagramname    sysname,
        @owner_id   int = null,
        @version    int,
        @definition     varbinary(max)
    )
    WITH EXECUTE AS ''dbo''
    AS
    BEGIN
        set nocount on

        declare @theId          int
        declare @retval         int
        declare @IsDbo          int

        declare @UIDFound       int
        declare @DiagId         int
        declare @ShouldChangeUID    int

        if(@diagramname is null)
        begin
            RAISERROR (''Invalid ARG'', 16, 1)
            return -1
        end

        execute as caller;
        select @theId = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID();     
        select @IsDbo = IS_MEMBER(N''db_owner''); 
        if(@owner_id is null)
            select @owner_id = @theId;
        revert;

        select @ShouldChangeUID = 0
        select @DiagId = diagram_id, @UIDFound = principal_id from dbo.sysdiagrams where principal_id = @owner_id and name = @diagramname 

        if(@DiagId IS NULL or (@IsDbo = 0 and @theId <> @UIDFound))
        begin
            RAISERROR (''Diagram does not exist or you do not have permission.'', 16, 1);
            return -3
        end

        if(@IsDbo <> 0)
        begin
            if(@UIDFound is null or USER_NAME(@UIDFound) is null) -- invalid principal_id
            begin
                select @ShouldChangeUID = 1 ;
            end
        end

        -- update dds data          
        update dbo.sysdiagrams set definition = @definition where diagram_id = @DiagId ;

        -- change owner
        if(@ShouldChangeUID = 1)
            update dbo.sysdiagrams set principal_id = @theId where diagram_id = @DiagId ;

        -- update dds version
        if(@version is not null)
            update dbo.sysdiagrams set version = @version where diagram_id = @DiagId ;

        return 0
    END
    '


    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_alterdiagram TO public
    DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_alterdiagram TO guest
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_dropdiagram') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_dropdiagram
    (
        @diagramname    sysname,
        @owner_id   int = null
    )
    WITH EXECUTE AS ''dbo''
    AS
    BEGIN
        set nocount on
        declare @theId          int
        declare @IsDbo          int

        declare @UIDFound       int
        declare @DiagId         int

        if(@diagramname is null)
        begin
            RAISERROR (''Invalid value'', 16, 1);
            return -1
        end

        EXECUTE AS CALLER;
        select @theId = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID();
        select @IsDbo = IS_MEMBER(N''db_owner''); 
        if(@owner_id is null)
            select @owner_id = @theId;
        REVERT; 

        select @DiagId = diagram_id, @UIDFound = principal_id from dbo.sysdiagrams where principal_id = @owner_id and name = @diagramname 
        if(@DiagId IS NULL or (@IsDbo = 0 and @UIDFound <> @theId))
        begin
            RAISERROR (''Diagram does not exist or you do not have permission.'', 16, 1)
            return -3
        end

        delete from dbo.sysdiagrams where diagram_id = @DiagId;

        return 0;
    END
    '


    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_dropdiagram TO public
    DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_dropdiagram TO guest
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.fn_diagramobjects') IS NULL and IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_diagramobjects() 
    RETURNS int
    WITH EXECUTE AS N''dbo''
    AS
    BEGIN
        declare @id_upgraddiagrams      int
        declare @id_sysdiagrams         int
        declare @id_helpdiagrams        int
        declare @id_helpdiagramdefinition   int
        declare @id_creatediagram   int
        declare @id_renamediagram   int
        declare @id_alterdiagram    int 
        declare @id_dropdiagram     int
        declare @InstalledObjects   int

        select @InstalledObjects = 0

        select  @id_upgraddiagrams = object_id(N''dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams''),
            @id_sysdiagrams = object_id(N''dbo.sysdiagrams''),
            @id_helpdiagrams = object_id(N''dbo.sp_helpdiagrams''),
            @id_helpdiagramdefinition = object_id(N''dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition''),
            @id_creatediagram = object_id(N''dbo.sp_creatediagram''),
            @id_renamediagram = object_id(N''dbo.sp_renamediagram''),
            @id_alterdiagram = object_id(N''dbo.sp_alterdiagram''), 
            @id_dropdiagram = object_id(N''dbo.sp_dropdiagram'')

        if @id_upgraddiagrams is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 1
        if @id_sysdiagrams is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 2
        if @id_helpdiagrams is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 4
        if @id_helpdiagramdefinition is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 8
        if @id_creatediagram is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 16
        if @id_renamediagram is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 32
        if @id_alterdiagram  is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 64
        if @id_dropdiagram is not null
            select @InstalledObjects = @InstalledObjects + 128

        return @InstalledObjects 
    END
    '


    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.fn_diagramobjects TO public
    DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.fn_diagramobjects TO guest
END

if IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    declare @val int
    select @val = 1
    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sysdiagrams') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'TABLE', N'sysdiagrams', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'PROCEDURE', N'sp_upgraddiagrams', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sp_helpdiagrams') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'PROCEDURE', N'sp_helpdiagrams', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'PROCEDURE', N'sp_helpdiagramdefinition', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sp_creatediagram') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'PROCEDURE', N'sp_creatediagram', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sp_renamediagram') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'PROCEDURE', N'sp_renamediagram', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sp_alterdiagram') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'PROCEDURE', N'sp_alterdiagram', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.sp_dropdiagram') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'PROCEDURE', N'sp_dropdiagram', NULL, NULL
    end

    if NOT EXISTS(  select major_id 
                    from sys.extended_properties
                    where major_id = object_id(N'dbo.fn_diagramobjects') and class = 1 and minor_id = 0 and name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support')
    begin
        exec sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', @val, 'SCHEMA', N'dbo', 'FUNCTION', N'fn_diagramobjects', NULL, NULL
    end
END

/* Clean up */
/*
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_diagramobjects
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_dropdiagram
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_alterdiagram
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_renamediagram
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_creatediagram
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_helpdiagrams
DROP TABLE dbo.sysdiagrams
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but first you have to select the option 'YES' to create the support objects to use database diagramming.Later run the below select query under the DB where Database Diagramming needs to be configured.

select * from  dtproperties

Alter the table dtproperties by inserting a column 'uvalue' to the table with the below query.As the column will be used in sproc

ALTER TABLE dtproperties
ADD [uvalue] nvarchar

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sysdiagrams') IS NOT NULL
        return 0;

    CREATE TABLE dbo.sysdiagrams
    (
        name sysname NOT NULL,
        principal_id int NOT NULL,  -- we may change it to varbinary(85)
        diagram_id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        version int,

        definition varbinary(max)
        CONSTRAINT UK_principal_name UNIQUE
        (
            principal_id,
            name
        )
    );


    -- Add this if we need to have some form of extended properties for diagrams */

    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sysdiagram_properties') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE dbo.sysdiagram_properties
        (
            diagram_id int,
            name sysname,
            value varbinary(max) NOT NULL
        )
    END


    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.dtproperties') IS NOT NULL
    begin
        insert into dbo.sysdiagrams
        (
            [name],
            [principal_id],
            [version],
            [definition]
        )
        select   
            convert(sysname, dgnm.[uvalue]),
            DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(N'dbo'),          -- will change to the sid of sa
            0,                          -- zero for old format, dgdef.[version],
            dgdef.[lvalue]
        from dbo.[dtproperties] dgnm
            inner join dbo.[dtproperties] dggd on dggd.[property] = 'DtgSchemaGUID' and dggd.[objectid] = dgnm.[objectid]   
            inner join dbo.[dtproperties] dgdef on dgdef.[property] = 'DtgSchemaDATA' and dgdef.[objectid] = dgnm.[objectid]

        where dgnm.[property] = 'DtgSchemaNAME' and dggd.[uvalue] like N'_EA3E6268-D998-11CE-9454-00AA00A3F36E_' 
        return 2;
    end
    return 1;
END
```

So finally right click on the DB to create Database diagramms[Invalid Column name[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ZDc.png)